# QuickBlox iOS SDK , Enabling Cloud Back-End Server AUTHKEY/APPLICATION ID TO APP DELEGATE

Tags: ios, swift, sdk, quickblox, appdelegate

I have followed all the guidelines of how to set up the iOS SDK that QuickBlox provides. I added the SDK through cocoa pods, added the run script with the snippet code.  example [here](http://quickblox.com/developers/IOS-how-to-connect-Quickblox-framework#Run_Script_Phase_for_Dynamic_framework/)!  I came to a crossroad and got stuck in how to add the auth-key, app-id.. ect. To The app delegate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you set the values in `AppDelegate` for `QuickBlox`

First

```
import Quickblox
```

in your `AppDelegate`, then in `didFinishLaunching` add this

```
QBSettings.setApplicationID(yourAppId)
QBSettings.setAuthKey(yourAuthKey)
QBSettings.setAuthSecret(yourAuthSecret)
QBSettings.setAccountKey(yourAccountKey)
```

Comment: Great! could you tell me how you managed to get that information, was it in the documentations?

Comment: Well I have used quickblox in one of my app and it is also mentioned in there docs, I have just converted the syntax to swift ;)

Comment: Sure got you,Thanks 